# c# How to check every single line with Regex.IsMatch

Tags: c#, regex, multiline

I'm using `new Regex("(?m)^\S+ [A-Z]{1,3}$").IsMatch(sStringToCheck)` to check a multiline string.

My issue is, that it only appears to validate the last line of the string.

This list passes:

- ABC-12345-DEF A
- ABC-12345-DEF A 123
- ABC-12345-DEF A

This list fails:

- ABC-12345-DEF A
- ABC-12345-DEF A
- ABC-12345-DEF A 123

However, I would like fail both, as each contains a not matching line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bool match = sStringToCheck
            .Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            .Any(line => new Regex(@"^\S+ [A-Z]{1,3}$").IsMatch(line));
```

will check every line.  Is that your goal?

Comment: I think I can work from that. My only issue is, that I have multiple checks, with only a few of them being multi line. Therefore the "(?m)". However, I could handle that using If/Else...

Comment: this should handle a single line string correctly too, as the split will just return the 1 item

Comment: Just need to use All() instead of Any(). Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Jonesy's answer is a better way of doing it, but for thoroughness, a non-LINQ-y way of doing it is to iterate over each line and OR that result with your overall answer:

```
bool match = false;
foreach(string s in sStringToCheck.Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)){
    match = match | new Regex("(?m)^\S+ [A-Z]{1,3}$").IsMatch(s);
}
```